# Cannot redeclare libraries_drush_command()

Tags: drush

After issuing the following command in the base drupal folder (/var/www/html)

```
$ drush status
```

I get the following response.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare libraries_drush_command() (previously declared in /var/www/html/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/libraries/libraries.drush.inc:13) in /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/libraries/libraries.drush.inc on line 25
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                 [error]
Error: Cannot redeclare libraries_drush_command() (previously declared in
/var/www/html/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/libraries/libraries.drush.inc:13) in
/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/libraries/libraries.drush.inc, line 25
```

This is a new server install using RHEL 6.4 (Santiago) and drush 6.0 installed through pear.

Where I might begin to fix this?

Comment: You've got two copies of the libraries module, one in profiles/common and one in sites/all - interestingly both are being included in the page load which suggests they're both installed somehow. Is this just a stock install of Drupal Commons?

Comment: This is version commons 3.3. I may have to let them know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/libraries/libraries.drush.inc cleared things up. I bungled things up somewhere. IRC #drupal-commons confirmed Clive's note above.

Comment: Make sure to mark your answer as complete. :)

Comment: I intend to mark it; however, there is a 2 day waiting period that must pass before I can.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, after redeclaring libraries module, it had some problem with features module as well, I assume this issue happens if you are using drupal profiles and there's duplication of modules in /profiles/PROFILENAME/modules/contrib/MODULENAME and also in /sites/all/modules/MODULENAME

Answer (score 0):

Drush seems to load duplicate command files as reported in https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/280
and looks like the they fixed the same https://drupal.org/node/644126